# Teamcity: Update env variable from pop up

Tags: variables, teamcity

I am trying to update an environmental variable in team city through a build's plan pop up (when you press run it pops up a window to set some var).

So far i the given value remain only for the specific build and then it discards.

Does anyone has any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the intended functionality: when using that popup, you are only modifying the parameter for that one run. For a permanent change, you need to open the project settings instead and go to the Parameters page.